# javascript .hide direction change

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide

With jQuery there is the hide() function.

When you add a duration to the hide function like so

```
$('#myclass').hide(1000);
<div id="myclass">
    <p>yolo</p>
</div>
```

It will start from the bottom and animate up over the course of one second.

My question is how could I change the direction it will start from.

Comment: Please elaborate, add all relevant tags, no tags in title, post code, live example. What have you tried so far? What failed?

Comment: This is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282047/jquery-animate-to-hide-and-show-elements-by-sliding-left-and-right?rq=1

Comment: @SteveKB how can you be so sure?

Comment: there is no hide function that takes in a duration in javascript without jquery. (unless you write it yourself)

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using jQuery

Comment: Everybody's given you suggestions (animate, position:absolute, the other SO post) but you seem to find problems with all of them, @TonyVentura! Complaining is not very attractive. Do some work, try them out, pick one & be happy.

Comment: I am not complaining, just curious :) and the answer from @JonathanLonowski was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for [`.hide( duration )`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/):

> When a duration, a plain object, or a "complete" function is provided, `.hide()` becomes an animation method. **The `.hide()` method animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously**. When these properties reach 0, the `display` style property is set to `none` to ensure that the element no longer affects the layout of the page.

The element only appears to be animating up and left because it's positioned by its top-left corner.

To have it animate in another direction, it'll have to be positioned on a different corner:

```
#myclass {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/W7hqy/

Comment: What about without changing the location of it. And if I need the class to have a relative position,

Comment: @TonyVentura It will need `position: absolute` (or `fixed`) to affect the animation. But, you can wrap it in a parent element with `position: relative` to hold it to a particular location. Though, you may want to also animate the `height` of the parent as well. http://jsfiddle.net/mFN9W/

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with the hide method **Assuming your using jQuery** you will need to use animate like so

```
$('element').animate({
    marginLeft: '-400px'
}, '5000',  function(){ 
    $(this).hide() 
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e6BBA/**

Comment: I really like the .hide() function cause I find it a lot more smooth and buggy. the animate has problems on mobile devices for me where as the .hide has none.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$('div').on('click', function(){
    $(this).animate({
        width: 0
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e6BBA/1/